# KissLog: mixed up Search Keywords

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kisslog

I have an odd Issue with KissLog.
We use KissLog Version 3.5.6 for an ASP.NET MVC Application.
In the "Search keywords" section of the details view of some entries there seams to be something mixed up. Here is an anonymised example:

```
Endpoint GET /details
Http referer /home
Search keywords
[
    "/details",
    "/login",
    "user-id:XXXX",
    "/home",
    "user1@mail.com",
    "/inbox/outgoing",
    "user2@mail.com",
    "someParameter:3",
    "/account",
    "/inbox",
    "user3@mail.com"
]
```

This entry should only contain information about the called endpoint */details* in this example and the other tabs 'Request', 'Response' and 'Logs' do only contain the information of the */details* call, but the 'Search keywords' section contains information about other calls as well. Even information of calls that were made by other users on other sessions.

Especially interesting that there are multiple emails of logged-in users listed.

On a web research I could not find anything regarding this issue so I post this question here hoping Catalin sees it :D

Maybe you can tell me if this is an issue with KissLog and it might be fixed in a newer version or if we just screwed up something in our implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen it :)

Prior to 4.0.0, KissLog was automatically generating search keywords without having the option to filter them, and, in some instances, duplicates would be created.
This might also be the issue that you are having.

If possible, please try to update the KissLog library to 5.0.0 as it contains many improvements and most probably will also fix the issue.

There are a few breaking changes compared to 3.5.6, but they should be relatively easy to solve. I can help if needed.

https://kisslog.net/Docs/SDK.change-log.index.html#kisslog-5-0-0

“Options.GenerateKeywords” has been renamed to “Options.GenerateSearchKeywords”.

https://github.com/KissLog-net/KissLog.Sdk/blob/f8200ffb49cd7e3157d0ee631e2256ba654b77f3/testApps/AspNet.Mvc/Global.asax.cs#L59

If this doesn’t help, i will perform additional troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We will update to the newest version soon and I let you know whether the issue is fixed.